# Why is the print function not giving the remaining output in a string in Python

Tags: python

I was trying to print a string, with whitespace after w(user-defined)characters from a string. But for some reason, it prints only the first w characters of the string. Can somebody explain the reason for this behavior?

```
string="ABCDEFGHIJK"
w=int(input())
i=0
for x in string:        
    if i < w:
        print(x, end = '')
        i=i+1
    if i > w:
        print('',end=' ')
        i=0
```

For given programme , when w=4,  I expect an output like

ABCD EFGH IJK

Comment: You could use some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your code. Think especially what happens in the case where `i == w`, and what you print when `i > w`...

Comment: You should check the condition where `i==w`, that is missing. That can cause the programme to not work properly.

Comment: @KoralpCatalsakal, that worked , i am so sorry for asking such a silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `i` is never greater than `w`.

As soon as `i` equals `w` you stop incrementing it.

Probably you intended `>` to be `>=` ?